# Bug in my jquery tab

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using Jquery UI Bootstrap tab. I have 2 tabs defined Product and Version

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="margin-top: 26px;">
      <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab">Version</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have also updated my fiddle. Didnt updated fiddle with my knockout code as it was too lengthy. Link is below

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashreva/CchjW/4/)

You can see in my fiddle is that when page loads it shows the column "Version name, Version code,Platform version" at bottom of my tab "Product". This is wrong. These columns should appear in my Version tab. What should i do for it?
In my actual application it look like this. I have marked line in red color which is appearing in my product tab.
[image: tab]

I need output of my tab as following

[image: tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/kSWQF/1/

```
 $('#myTab').tabs();
```

Make sure to check for these references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Edit:

To show a paricular tab by tab index:

```
$('#myTab').tabs("option", "selected", 1 ); //index ie zero based, here selects second tab.
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kSWQF/2/

Comment: i get error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs'

Comment: Add `jQuery UI` library reference.. jQuery Tabs are from `jQuery UI`.. See updated answer..

Comment: how to activate certain tab based on click event. Right now i have to click on particular tab to see content below it. It should automatically display content.  I tried  $('#myTab a[href="#version"]').show();  but doesnt work.

Comment: Just last query. I cant see in css where exactly to change the color tab. Currently its grey. I want it to be transparent. Many thanks for your help. Also i didnt understand what i did wrong. You just added one more div on top of all and called $('#myTab').tabs(); I was already doing something like    $('#myTab a[href="#product"]').tab('show'); and it was showing me correct tabs. Only issue was that those column names were appearing in page load

Comment: Well, `jQuery UI Tabs` demands such a format... You can read the documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)..

Comment: For tab color on hover : `.nav-tabs > li > a:hover { // new style !important}`

Comment: but i am sure this can be changed as it it just css. But not sure where

Comment: i dont need anything for hover. I just want to get rid of grey color on tabs

Comment: Where is this default style defined? I searched for .nav-tabs but cant find where grey color is defined

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />` reference if included...

Comment: what you did? Also still there is grey color on actual tabs

Comment: Please tell me how you made it transparent?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23569/discussion-between-ashreva-and-a-v)

Comment: i am not able to chat. I typed few things but when i click on send nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is knockout related, but shouldn't you have all the content for each tab within the tab pane div? Whereas you have a div for the header for products and a div for the content. All your content should be inside the div with the id that you reference in the href of the tab.

Comment: Please can you tell me how